# How to calculate significance for ranking metric

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, experiment-design, multiple-comparisons

My goal is to use nDCG metric as north star and then run A/B experiments to measure this metric. However, I am confused how to compute whether the metric is statistically significant or not.

My understanding is that if i have iid data in control and treatment, then its easy to this. So for eg:

If my data is like

```
control: 1,3,2, 1,1,3,..  (where each of this number indicate whether a document is relevant or not).. 
treatment: 3,3... 1..
```

then we can use something from [here](https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_Statistics/Book%3A_Introductory_Statistics_(Shafer_and_Zhang)/09%3A_Two-Sample_Problems/9.01%3A_Comparison_of_Two_Population_Means-_Large_Independent_Samples) to calculate statsig..

However, in ranking the issue is that the relevance is not flattened but it is based on per query basis.
So control looks like:

```
q1: [r1, r2, ... rk]
q2: [r1,r2,... rk]
..
```

And treatment also has similar data.
and so on..
Now, my question is that if i naively flatten this list of r1,r2 etc.. then the data is not truly iid? My stats is not that strong but wouldn't that cause the issue?
What's the right way to calculate statistical significance here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless the observations are already correlated in a way that cannot be ignored (e.g. multiple records from the same person - in that case you either need to change the bootstrapping scheme below or bootstrapping may no longer be appropriate), a nice way to work with metrics that don't have a statistical available for them is bootstrapping (which nicely applies in the A/B testing setting). You draw $B$ samples from your data with replacement (each of the same size as your original data) and then you calculate the metric of interest (e.g. nDGC - whatever that is - for each of two groups, or the difference in nDGC between two groups) for each of these $B$ samples. Your estimate is the observed difference, and a 95% confidence interval is given by the 2.5th and 97.5th percentile  of the metrics calculated for the the different bootstrap samples (there's of course more sophisticated versions than these simple quantile boostrap confidence intervals). Have a look at some vignettes on bootstrapping and see whether this could work for your problem.